# Problem with an example of semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

I was trying to understand [Example 7.15](https://books.google.fi/books?id=4x8BCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=rotman%20example%207.15&source=bl&ots=VuvEfFSuKS&sig=UixVNAGvltcR036OI3hMkeezHJM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ9JXQ9KTPAhUIfywKHYk0AZUQ6AEIJzAD#v=onepage&q=rotman%20example%207.15&f=false) from Rotman's Introduction to the Theory of Groups. The problem I'm having is maybe a bit silly and not strictly about semidirect products, but I don't understand how I apply $\theta_{x}$ to an element $a \in K$. My understanding is that, for each $x^i$, we have a map defined like this

$$\theta_{x^i} = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\i&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

but then what is $\theta_{x^i}(a)$? How is this map even an automorphism of $K$? $K$ isn't necessarily going to be a group of matrices, right?

Thanks!

Comment: No, $K$ is not, but the automorphism group of $K$ is, since $K$ is elementary abelian.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm not familiar at all with these kinds of groups, and they're not relevant to the work I'm doing right now, but I need to include this example. I can refer the reader to other sources that discuss the topic, but I'd need to know how $\theta_{x^i}$ is applied to $a$. Suggestions? :)

Comment: Well, what does $a$ look like since it is an element of $K$?

Comment: All I know is that $a^p=e$.

Comment: $K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p\times\mathbb{Z}/p$.

Comment: Okay, I sort of see that, but that doesn't quite explain how to apply $\theta_x$... I mean, if the elements of $K$ were pairs, then I suppose it could be a matrix product kind of thing, but in my understanding, $K$ has as many elements as $\mathbb{Z}/p \times \mathbb{Z}/p$, but they could well not be pairs. Or could they?

Comment: It is isomorphic to it as a group, so yes, they are indeed pairs.